# LNK2005 and LNK 1160 in vc++

Tags: c++, visual-c++, lnk2005

I'm new to c++ and vc++ and i used 3rd party library `bioapi`. I successfully integrated it but when I tried to use the sample working program of `bioapi`, the `misc.h` and `misc.cpp`, i got an error `LNK2005` AND `LNK1160`.

By the way I created this as CLR project in vc++ and it seems I cannot use /FORCE or /FORCE:MULTIPLE.

Here's the misc.h

```
/*---------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*                                                               */
/* Copyright  (C)  NEC  Corporation  2011                        */
/* NEC  CONFIDENTIAL  AND  PROPRIETARY                           */
/*                                                               */
/*  All rights reserved by NEC Corporation. This program must be */
/* used solely for the purpose for which it was furnished by NEC */
/* Corporation.  No part of this program may be reproduced or    */
/* disclosed to others, in any form, without the prior written   */
/* permission of NEC Corporation.  Use of copyright notice does  */
/* not evidence publication of this program.                     */
/*                                                               */
/* NEC Corporation accepts no responsibility for any damages     */
/* resulting from the use of this sample code.                   */
/* This sample code is provided "AS IS", and its user assume all */
/* risks when using it.                                          */
/*                                                               */
/*---------------------------------------------------------------*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <sys/types.h>          /* for stat()   */
#include <sys/stat.h>           /* for stat()   */
#include <direct.h>             /* for _mkdir() */

//#include "stdafx.h"
//#include "resource.h"
#include "BioAPI.h"             /* include BioAPI Framework */
#include "BioAPI_util.h"        /* include BioAPI Framework */

#include "hf-pid-bsp.h"

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------
*
*  define
*
*--------------------------------------------------------------------*/
#define MaxN           1000     /* Max Identify Num */
#define MaxEnrollNum   999      /* Max Enroll Num   */
#define MaxID          9999     /* Max Enroll ID    */
#define MinID          0        /* Min Enroll ID    */
#define Timeout        10000     /* Capture Timeout  */


#define ERRCODE_ID_INPUT_ERROR          -100
#define ERRCODE_NOT_ENROLLED            -101

#define SECTION_IDENTIFYPARAM           "IdentifyParam"
#define KEY_MAXNUMBEROFRESULTS          "MaxNumberOfResults"

#define MESS_ALLEADY_STARTED            "Application is already started."
#define MESS_USERREG                    "UserReg"
#define MESS_AP_ERROR                   "Error"
#define MESS_ID_INPUT_ERROR             TEXT("Please input a value in the range of 0001-9999")
#define MESS_NOT_ENROLLED               TEXT("The ID does not exist for")
#define MESS_BIOAPI_ERROR               TEXT("BioAPI Error")
#define MESS_BIOAPI_ERROR_CODE          TEXT("BioAPI Error Code: %ld")
#define MESS_ENROLL                     "Enrollment"
#define MESS_ENROLL_FAILED              "Enroll process is failed."
#define MESS_ENROLL_SUCCESSED           "Enroll process is successed."
#define MESS_VERIFY                     "Verification"
#define MESS_VERIFY_FAILED              "Verification failed."
#define MESS_VERIFY_OK                  "Verification process is successed."
#define MESS_VERIFY_NG                  "Verification process is failed."
#define MESS_IDENTIFY                   "Identification"
#define MESS_IDENTIFY_FAILED            "Identification failed."
#define MESS_IDENTIFY_OK                "Identification process is successed."
#define MESS_IDENTIFY_NG                "Identification process is failed."
#define MESS_CAPTION                    "Sample Application"
#define MESS_END                        "Exit"
#define MESS_MESSAGE1                   "Please choose the function."
#define MESS_CLOSE                      "Close"
#define MESS_ENROLL1                    "Enroll"
#define MESS_ENROLL2                    "CreateTemplate"
#define MESS_MESSAGE2                   "After entering ID(0001`9999), Please click [Enroll] button or [CreateTemplate] button."
#define MESS_ID                         "ID:"
#define MESS_ONETOONE                   "1:1 Verification"
#define MESS_ONETON                     "1:N Identification"
#define MESS_MESSAGE3                   "Please choose the verification method."
#define MESS_VERIFY1                    "VerifyMatch"
#define MESS_VERIFY2                    "Verify"
#define MESS_MESSAGE4                   "After entering ID(0001`9999), Please click [Verify] button or [Verification] button."
#define MESS_IDENTIFY1                  "IdentifyMatch"
#define MESS_IDENTIFY2                  "Identify"
#define MESS_MESSAGE5                   "Please click [Identify] button or [Identification] button."
#define MESS_AUTH_MESSAGE               "Identification process is successed.\r\nMaxNumberOfResults = (%d)\r\nNumberOfResults = (%d)\r\nID:"
#define MESS_INIFILE_GET_FAILED         "sample.ini get failed."

#define PATH_ENROLLED_FILE              ".\\enroll\\*.dat"
#define PATH_ENROLLED_FILE_IN_ID        ".\\enroll\\%04d_*.dat"
#define PATH_ENROLLED_DIRECTORY         ".\\enroll"
#define PATH_ENROLLED_NAME              TEXT(".\\enroll\\%s_%03d.dat")
#define PATH_ENROLLED_DIRECTORY         ".\\enroll"
#define INIFILE_NAME                    ".\\sample.ini"

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------
*
*  global
*
*--------------------------------------------------------------------*/
static BioAPI_HANDLE                gModuleHandle;
static BioAPI_RETURN                bioReturn;
static BioAPI_BIR_HANDLE            StoredTemplate;
static BioAPI_INPUT_BIR             CapturedBIR;
static BioAPI_INPUT_BIR             ProcessedBIR;
static BioAPI_INPUT_BIR             StoredBIR;
static BioAPI_BIR_HANDLE            CapturedTemplate;
static BioAPI_BOOL                  boolie = BioAPI_FALSE;
static BioAPI_BOOL                  result;
static BioAPI_FRR                   frr = HF_PID_BSP_LEVEL_MIDDLE;    // Security Level
static BioAPI_FAR                   AchievedFAR = 1;
static uint32                       MaxNumberOfResults = 1;
static uint32                       NumberOfResults;
static BioAPI_CANDIDATE_ARRAY_PTR   Candidates;
static BioAPI_INPUT_BIR             InputBirProcessed_PopulationElem[MaxN];
static BioAPI_IDENTIFY_POPULATION   *Population;
static BioAPI_BIR_PTR               lpPopulationAryBIRData_Member;
static HANDLE                       hSearch;
static char                         fname_db[MAX_PATH + 1];
static char                         fid_db[MAX_PATH + 1];
static WIN32_FIND_DATA              fd;
static BioAPI_BIR_ARRAY_POPULATION  lPopulationAryBIRData;
static BioAPI_BIR_PTR               FullBIR;
static BioAPI_UUID                  BSPUuid = HF_PID_BSP_UUID;
typedef struct stBIR_AND_FileName {
    BioAPI_BIR* pPopulationBIRPointer;
    char        lptszUserName[_MAX_PATH];
}BIR_AND_FILENAME;
static BIR_AND_FILENAME             RetBIR_And_FileName[MaxN];
static BioAPI_CANDIDATE_ARRAY       lpWorkCandidates;
static char                         IdentificationMessage[MAX_PATH + 1];

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------
*
* function
*
*--------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void PrintErrorCode(BioAPI_RETURN bioReturn);
void LoadBSP(BioAPI_HANDLE_PTR gModuleHandle);
void ReleaseBSP(BioAPI_HANDLE_PTR gModuleHandle);
BioAPI_RETURN OutputToFile(BioAPI_HANDLE gModuleHandle, LPTSTR lptszUserName, BioAPI_BIR_HANDLE BirHandle);
BioAPI_RETURN InputFromFile(LPTSTR lptszUserName, BioAPI_INPUT_BIR * InputBir, uint32 count);

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------
*
*  End of misc.h
*
*--------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

misc.cpp

```
/*---------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*                                                               */
/* Copyright  (C)  NEC  Corporation  2011                        */
/* NEC  CONFIDENTIAL  AND  PROPRIETARY                           */
/*                                                               */
/*  All rights reserved by NEC Corporation. This program must be */
/* used solely for the purpose for which it was furnished by NEC */
/* Corporation.  No part of this program may be reproduced or    */
/* disclosed to others, in any form, without the prior written   */
/* permission of NEC Corporation.  Use of copyright notice does  */
/* not evidence publication of this program.                     */
/*                                                               */
/* NEC Corporation accepts no responsibility for any damages     */
/* resulting from the use of this sample code.                   */
/* This sample code is provided "AS IS", and its user assume all */
/* risks when using it.                                          */
/*                                                               */
/*---------------------------------------------------------------*/

//#include "stdafx.h"
#include "misc.h"

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------
*
*  PrintErrorCode
*
*--------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void PrintErrorCode(
    BioAPI_RETURN bioReturn     /* INPUT : BioAPI Error Code */
)
{
    TCHAR szMessage[_MAX_PATH];

    // ID Input Error
    if (bioReturn == ERRCODE_ID_INPUT_ERROR)
    {
        wsprintf(szMessage, MESS_ID_INPUT_ERROR);
        MessageBox(GetActiveWindow(), szMessage, MESS_BIOAPI_ERROR, MB_OK | MB_ICONSTOP);
    }
    // Not Enrolled Error
    else if (bioReturn == ERRCODE_NOT_ENROLLED)
    {
        wsprintf(szMessage, MESS_NOT_ENROLLED);
        MessageBox(GetActiveWindow(), szMessage, MESS_BIOAPI_ERROR, MB_OK | MB_ICONSTOP);
    }
    // BioAPI Error
    else
    {
        wsprintf(szMessage, MESS_BIOAPI_ERROR_CODE, bioReturn);
        MessageBox(GetActiveWindow(), szMessage, MESS_BIOAPI_ERROR, MB_OK | MB_ICONSTOP);
    }

    return;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------
*
*  LoadBSP
*
*--------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void LoadBSP(
    BioAPI_HANDLE_PTR gModuleHandle     /* INPUT : BSP Module Handle */
)
{
    BioAPI_VERSION bioVersion;
    bioVersion.Major = BioAPI_MAJOR;
    bioVersion.Minor = BioAPI_MINOR;

    bioReturn = BioAPI_Init(&bioVersion, 0, NULL, 0, NULL);
    if (BioAPI_OK != bioReturn)
    {
        PrintErrorCode(bioReturn);
        return;
    }
    bioReturn = BioAPI_ModuleLoad(&BSPUuid, 0, NULL, 0);
    if (BioAPI_OK != bioReturn)
    {
        PrintErrorCode(bioReturn);
        return;
    }
    bioReturn = BioAPI_ModuleAttach(&BSPUuid, &bioVersion, &BioAPIWinMemoryFuncs, 0, 0, 0, 0, NULL, 0, NULL, gModuleHandle);
    if (BioAPI_OK != bioReturn)
    {
        PrintErrorCode(bioReturn);
        return;
    }

    return;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------
*
*  ReleaseBSP
*
*--------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void ReleaseBSP(
    BioAPI_HANDLE_PTR gModuleHandle     /* INPUT : BSP Module Handle */
)
{
    if (gModuleHandle != 0)
    {
        bioReturn = BioAPI_ModuleDetach(*gModuleHandle);
        if (BioAPI_OK != bioReturn)
        {
            PrintErrorCode(bioReturn);
            return;
        }
        gModuleHandle = 0;
    }
    bioReturn = BioAPI_ModuleUnload(&BSPUuid, NULL, 0);
    if (BioAPI_OK != bioReturn)
    {
        PrintErrorCode(bioReturn);
        return;
    }
    bioReturn = BioAPI_Terminate();
    if (BioAPI_OK != bioReturn)
    {
        PrintErrorCode(bioReturn);
        return;
    }

    return;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------
*
*  OutputToFile
*
*--------------------------------------------------------------------*/
BioAPI_RETURN OutputToFile(
    BioAPI_HANDLE gModuleHandle,    /* INPUT : BSP Module Handle */
    LPTSTR lptszUserName,           /* INPUT : Save File Neme    */
    BioAPI_BIR_HANDLE BirHandle     /* INPUT : Save BIR Data     */
)
{
    TCHAR           szFileName[_MAX_PATH];
    HANDLE          hFile;
    DWORD           dwBytesToWrite, dwBytesWritten;
    BioAPI_BIR_PTR  birData = NULL;
    BioAPI_RETURN   bioReturn;
    uint32          count = 0;
    struct stat     buff;

    // Retrieve the BIR from the BSP
    bioReturn = BioAPI_GetBIRFromHandle(gModuleHandle, BirHandle, &birData);
    if (bioReturn != BioAPI_OK)
    {
        return bioReturn;
    }

    // Search Save FileName
    _mkdir(PATH_ENROLLED_DIRECTORY);
    while (1)
    {
        if (++count > MaxEnrollNum)
        {
            return -1; // Can't make file
        }
        wsprintf(szFileName, PATH_ENROLLED_NAME, lptszUserName, count);
        if ((stat(szFileName, &buff) != 0))
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    // Open the file 
    hFile = CreateFile(szFileName, GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CREATE_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        return 0; // this return value is ignored anyway
    }

    // Write the header
    WriteFile(hFile, &(birData->Header), sizeof(BioAPI_BIR_HEADER), &dwBytesWritten, NULL);

    // Write the biometric data
    dwBytesToWrite = LocalEndian4(birData->Header.Length) - sizeof(BioAPI_BIR_HEADER);
    WriteFile(hFile, birData->BiometricData, dwBytesToWrite, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);

    // Write the signature if present
    if (birData->Signature)
    {
        WriteFile(hFile, &(birData->Signature->Length), 4, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
        dwBytesToWrite = LocalEndian4(birData->Signature->Length);
        WriteFile(hFile, birData->Signature->Data, dwBytesToWrite, &dwBytesWritten, NULL);
    }

    // Close the file
    CloseHandle(hFile);

    // Free all the memory allocated for the BIR
    if (birData != NULL) {
        GlobalFree(birData->BiometricData);
        if (birData->Signature)
        {
            GlobalFree(birData->Signature->Data);
            GlobalFree(birData->Signature);
        }
        GlobalFree(birData);
    }
    return BioAPI_OK;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------------
*
*  InputFromFile
*
*--------------------------------------------------------------------*/
BioAPI_RETURN InputFromFile(
    LPTSTR lptszUserName,           /* INPUT  : Load File Name      */
    BioAPI_INPUT_BIR * InputBir,    /* OUTPUT : Load BIR Data       */
    uint32 count                    /* INPUT  : User Enroll Number  */
)
{
    TCHAR       szFileName[_MAX_PATH];
    HANDLE      hFile;
    DWORD       dwBytesToRead, dwBytesRead;
    BioAPI_BIR  *bir;

    // Open the file 
    wsprintf(szFileName, PATH_ENROLLED_NAME, lptszUserName, count);
    hFile = CreateFile(szFileName, GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        return BioAPIERR_BSP_RECORD_NOT_FOUND; // Return this BSP error if the file isn't present
    }

    // Read the header in, to determine the size
    dwBytesToRead = sizeof(BioAPI_BIR_HEADER);
    bir = (BioAPI_BIR*)GlobalAlloc(GPTR, sizeof(BioAPI_BIR));
    if (!bir)
    {
        return !BioAPI_OK;
    }
    ReadFile(hFile, &(bir->Header), dwBytesToRead, &dwBytesRead, NULL);

    // Read the biometric data
    dwBytesToRead = LocalEndian4(bir->Header.Length) - sizeof(BioAPI_BIR_HEADER);
    bir->BiometricData = (BioAPI_BIR_BIOMETRIC_DATA_PTR)GlobalAlloc(GPTR, dwBytesToRead);
    if (!bir->BiometricData)
    {
        return !BioAPI_OK;
    }
    ReadFile(hFile, bir->BiometricData, dwBytesToRead, &dwBytesRead, NULL);

    // Read the signature if present
    dwBytesToRead = 0;
    if (ReadFile(hFile, &dwBytesToRead, 4, &dwBytesRead, NULL) != 0 && dwBytesToRead != 0)
    {
        bir->Signature = (BioAPI_DATA_PTR)GlobalAlloc(GPTR, sizeof(BioAPI_DATA));
        if (!bir->Signature)
        {
            return !BioAPI_OK;
        }
        bir->Signature->Length = dwBytesToRead;
        dwBytesToRead = LocalEndian4(dwBytesToRead);
        bir->Signature->Data = (uint8 *)GlobalAlloc(GPTR, dwBytesToRead);
        if (!bir->Signature->Data)
        {
            return !BioAPI_OK;
        }
        ReadFile(hFile, bir->Signature->Data, dwBytesToRead, &dwBytesRead, NULL);
    }

    // Close the file
    CloseHandle(hFile);

    // Set up the return values
    InputBir->InputBIR.BIR = bir;
    InputBir->Form = BioAPI_FULLBIR_INPUT;

    return BioAPI_OK;
}
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------
*
*  End of misc.cpp
*
*--------------------------------------------------------------------*/
```

Errors:

```
1>libucrt.lib(exit.obj) : error LNK2005: _cexit already defined in ucrtd.lib(ucrtbased.dll)
1>libucrt.lib(onexit.obj) : error LNK2005: _crt_at_quick_exit already defined in ucrtd.lib(ucrtbased.dll)
1>libucrt.lib(onexit.obj) : error LNK2005: _crt_atexit already defined in ucrtd.lib(ucrtbased.dll)
1>libucrt.lib(onexit.obj) : error LNK2005: _execute_onexit_table already defined in ucrtd.lib(ucrtbased.dll)
1>libucrt.lib(onexit.obj) : error LNK2005: _initialize_onexit_table already defined in ucrtd.lib(ucrtbased.dll)
1>libucrt.lib(onexit.obj) : error LNK2005: _register_onexit_function already defined in ucrtd.lib(ucrtbased.dll)
1>libucrt.lib(environment_initialization.obj) : error LNK2005: _initialize_narrow_environment already defined in ucrtd.lib(ucrtbased.dll)
1>libucrt.lib(exception_filter.obj) : error LNK2005: _seh_filter_dll already defined in ucrtd.lib(ucrtbased.dll)
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'MSVCRTD' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>LINK : warning LNK4098: defaultlib 'ucrtd.lib' conflicts with use of other libs; use /NODEFAULTLIB:library
1>C:\Users\Laptop-attendance\source\repos\Bioapitest\x64\Debug\Bioapitest.exe : fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found
```

Comment: what exactly are the errors that the linker has thrown?

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to include the errors. I already updated it now.

Comment: Have a look at this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72zdcz6f.aspx and see if any of the proposed solutions work for you

Comment: Looks like you're linking to both debug and release revision of the C run-time. Maybe your 3rd party library is build in release and you're building in debug. Link to the debug version of the library or if not possible build your application in release.